# Fetching IPFS data Subgraph Studio does not support mappings with ipfs methods

Tags: the-graph, subgraph

I am using the graph and am looking to get NFT meta data via ipfs in a transfer event. Everything works as expected unless I try to fetch meta data via ipfs

The schema looks like

```
type Example @entity {
  id: ID!
  createdAtTimeStamp: BigInt!
  contentURI: String!
  tokenId: BigInt!
  name: String!
  description: String!
  image: String!
  externalURL: String!
}
```

and the transfer event

```
const IPFSHASH = "EXAMPLE_IPFS_HASH";

export function handleTransfer(event: TransferEvent): void {

  let example = Example.load(event.params.tokenId.toString());

  if (!example) {
    example = new Example(event.params.tokenId.toString());
    example.createdAtTimeStamp = event.block.timestamp;
    example.tokenId = event.params.tokenId;

    let exampleContract = ExampleContract.bind(event.address);

    example.contentURI = exampleContract.tokenURI(event.params.tokenId);
    const ipfsUrl = "/" + event.params.tokenId.toString() + ".json";

    let metadata = ipfs.cat(ipfshash + token.tokenURI);
if(metadata) {

.....
}

}
```

And I cannot get it to compile correctly whenever I use the ipfs lib from the graph with error  `Failed to compile data source mapping: Subgraph Studio does not support mappings with ipfs methods.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, the Graph Network does not yet support ipfs.cat and ipfs.map, and developers should not deploy subgraphs using that functionality to the network via the Studio.

See: https://thegraph.com/docs/en/developing/creating-a-subgraph/

Comment: Correct, however it can be achieved with the hosted services and in your subgraph.yaml
 `ipfsOnEthereumContracts`